# Visual Studio 2022 Preview. Debugging Can not evaluate children with Blazor WASM project

Tags: visual-studio, blazor-webassembly

I have noticed that when I hit a breakpoint in my Blazor WASW project if I am trying to look at a Collection object  to examine the contents I receive the information:
"Children could not be evaluated"

Is this normal behaviour due to  problems debugging WASM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated NuGet packages to 6.02.All working now.